# PHP File Upload .htaccess Security

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, upload

I am designing a website were users can upload files and download them. The files will only be stored for download.

What I have done so far:
When a user uploads a file, I am currently checking the file extension and mime type against my whitelist formats.

```
      if (@is_uploaded_file($this->_tempname)) {
                $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($this->_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                $mimeType = $finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($this->_tempname));
                if (false === $ext = array_search($mimeType, $this->allowed_formats, true)) {
                    return false;
                }

                //Here I just move the file to the path...
      }
```

I am trying to secure the uploads folder with .htaccess to prevent file from being executed like .php etc. Since I don't know much about .htaccess, I would like some help.

What I have so far in my .htaccess is

```
         IndexIgnore *
        AddHandler cgi-script .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .php8 .pl .py .js .jsp .asp .htm .html .shtml .sh .cgi
         Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
```

But I don't know if the .htaccess is even working or how to test to see if it is.

The upload folder structure is as follows.

- Uploads

  - user1 <- The name of the user
  - user2
  - user3
  - .htaccess

Now, what I would like the .htaccess to do is disable the php engine for all the sub-folders such as user1 etc. I would also want to prevent any file from being executed and prevent .htaccess overwrite and any other security feature that could be included in the .htaccess to prevent users to upload files with malicious intentions.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I also rename the file using the unique php feature and encoding with md5 before uploading them to the uploads folder.

Comment: What a certain forum I use used to do is having a whitelist of extensions that were allowed to execute (e.g. png files). Any other filetype would be encoded with a key, and stored as `randomname.bin`. If they were downloaded, they had to be downloaded via their download-page, which would decode them with the stored key as the name that was stored in the database. Remember too that a file `a.php.old.png` can be executed as a php script under Apache, as apache recognizes php, old and png as extensions.

Comment: So is there any way to prevent apache from executing files with a particular extension? I also forgot to mention that before I move the file, I rename the file name to a random name using md5.

Comment: If you do not need access to them directly, you could use a `Deny from all` ([reading material](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)). If you md5 the filenames, make sure that you check for collisions.